# nodejs xhr POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am using nodejs and trying to make a POST command to a server. I am also using node-xmlHttpRequest (driverdan's module).  I am having issues with the content-type and get the error:

```
{
  "response":{
    "errorCode":"UNKNOWN_ERROR","message":"Content type 
    'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported","detail":"Content type 
    'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
  },"version":"1.0"
}
```

I need the content-type to be JSON, not text.  I have tested the code with GET and it works fine.

Here is my code:

```js
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var sys = require('util');
    var json_text2 = { "username": "admin","password": "-----" };
    var apicem_ip = "sandboxapic.cisco.com:9443";
    var apic_url = 'https://'+apicem_ip+'/api/v1/ticket';
    //- var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        sys.puts("State: " + this.readyState);

        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            sys.puts("Complete.\nBody length: " + this.responseText.length);
            sys.puts("Body:\n" + this.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.open("POST",apic_url,true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    xhr.responseType = 'JSON';
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(json_text2));
    app.locals.apic_nd = xhr.responseText;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For goodness sake, it's nodejs.  Don't use an XMLHttpRequest emulator.  Why emulate a bad browser interface in node.js.  Use the http or the request module.  I'd personally use the request module.

Comment: I am new to node (and js), clearly.  I will Google what you are talking about because I have no idea .   I was just taking what someone did in js and tried to port it to node.  I come from IT, not dev...  Thanks for the pointer! I'll follow up later today.

Comment: @jfriend00can you elaborate on why xhr is a bad choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to jfriend00 I got it working (not sure how to upvote his comment.  But here is the code I used:

```
var apicem_ip = "sandboxapic.cisco.com:9443";
var apic_url = 'https://'+apicem_ip+'/api/v1/ticket';

var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://'+apicem_ip+'/api/v1/ticket',
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: '{ "username": "admin", "password": "----"}'
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  console.log("callback function");
  if (!error) {
    var info = (JSON.parse(body));
    console.log(info);
    console.log("status 200");

  }
  else {
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
  }
}

request.post(options, callback);
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to the `request` library?